# What is the first known use of the proverb “out of sight is out of mind”?

Tags: expressions, proverbs

It is said that Shakespeare and Hopkins used [‘out of sight is out of mind’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_sight,_out_of_mind).

But when was this phrase first used?

Comment: The OED has: "a1500  tr. Thomas à Kempis *De Imitatione Christi* (Trin. Dublin) (1893) 30 (MED),   Whan man is oute of siȝt, sone he passiþ oute of mynde." But I don't know whether that's the first known usage.

Answer (score 1):

It says [HERE](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/274400.html) that, even though the expression was already in use as early as the 13th Century, the first *printed* citation is from 1562:

> The earliest printed citation of a link with memory and the sight of something is in John Heywood's Woorkes. A dialogue conteynyng prouerbes and epigrammes, 1562, as reprinted by the Spenser Society, 1867:
>
> "Out of sight out of minde."